# External URL in nav bar doesn't work in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently set up a theme running bootstrap to run as our website. Everything works fine, including external URLs that have been placed in the HTML.

The thing is, the actual navigation bar does not register the external URLs and will not open them when you click. It's being stopped by the JS "Magnific Popup" but I do not know why specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the website, and the navigation bar with the error is top-right.

[Rustoria Website](http://rustoria.uk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually caused by preventDefault() method inside the javascript. I believe the navigation originally intended for anchor scrolls. Inside the main.js file, you will find the following code in line 62.

```
// Page Nav
var clickMenu = function() {

    $('#navbar a:not([class="external"])').click(function(event){
        var section = $(this).data('nav-section'),
            navbar = $('#navbar');

            if ( $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length ) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top
                }, 500);
           }

        if ( navbar.is(':visible')) {
            navbar.removeClass('in');
            navbar.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });


};
```

As you can see the function is preventing the default action. After reading this function, you can see the jquery selector is looking for the a tags **without** "external" class. Simply adding "external" class to the a tag will fix the issue.

Comment: Which main.js file is that? Can you provide a link?